# max, min value of list of lists at 1st column

Tags: python, opencv, contour

Lets say I have a list of lists.  For example,

`([[[362, 239]], [[362, 367]], [[386, 367]], [[386, 239]]])`

How can I get the max values for column 1 and 2 separately?

Answer for the example should be:

```
col1_max = 386, col2_max = 367
```

I already tried:

```
col1_max = max(cnts.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]
print col1_max
```

But here I get just

```
errorcode: "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'iteritems'"
```

UPDATE:

I will re-phrase my question again in a different way
right now I want to write a code to

- detect objects
- centers of these

The code so far is:

```py
import imutils
import cv2
import os, os.path

DIR = 'pics/'
numberOfPictures = len([name for name in os.listdir(DIR) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(DIR, name))])

for i in range(0, numberOfPictures):
    image = cv2.imread('pics/' + str(i) + '.png', 0)
    thresh = cv2.threshold(image, 60, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
    
    cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = cnts[0] if imutils.is_cv2() else cnts[1]
    
    j = 1
    
    for c in cnts:
        M = cv2.moments(c)
        
        if M["m00"] != 0:
            cX = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
            cY = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])
            
        else:
            continue
        
        print cnts
          
        j = j + 1
    
        cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
        cv2.circle(image, (cX, cY), 7, (255, 255, 255), -1)
        cv2.putText(image, "center", (cX - 20, cY - 20), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (255, 255, 255), 2)
    
        cv2.imshow("Image", image)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This alone works good but now I want to get the max and min values out of the cnts.

I use cv2.findContours for creating my cnts

`cnts = [array([[[362, 239]], [[362, 367]], [[386, 367]], [[386, 239]]])]`

How can I extract the max value for the 1st column and the max value for the 2nd column?

Comment: That's actually a list of lists of lists.. is that intentional?

Answer (score 1):

In case your input is a list of lists (unlike what you have in your example), this should work:

```
li = [[362, 239], [362, 367], [386, 367], [386, 239]]

def get_max_by_col(li, col):
    # col - 1 is used to 'hide' the fact lists' indexes are zero-based from the caller
    return max(li, key=lambda x: x[col - 1])[col - 1]

print(get_max_by_col(li, 1))
>> 386

print(get_max_by_col(li, 2))
>> 367
```

**Update** if you do have a list of lists of lists, change the line
`return max(li, key=lambda x: x[col - 1])[col - 1]`
in the above code to
`return max(li, key=lambda x: x[0][col - 1])[0][col - 1]`.

Comment: ok i will try it

but what do you mean if i have a list of lists?
isnt this one?

Comment: @M.Wittig, no, `[[[362, 239]], [[362, 367]], [[386, 367]], [[386, 239]]]` is a list of lists of lists

Comment: ah i see and what would be a possible solution for this case? sry i am new to python ^^

Comment: i used your code but everything i get is

>>"return max(cnts, key=lambda x: x[0][col - 1])[0][col - 1]
IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1"

Comment: @M.Wittig what is `cnts`? This code works for me with `[[[362, 239]], [[362, 367]], [[386, 367]], [[386, 239]]]`

Comment: cnts i the list of list of lists in my code, could it be that its more like a array of list of lists? is this possible


i use spyder, the variable explorer sasys the following for my cnts

[array([[[362, 239]], [[362, 367]], [[386, 367]], [[386, 239]]])]

sorry to bother you so much

Comment: It works with example your provided in your question, so verify your input

Comment: if i print cnts i get [array([[[362, 239]], [[362, 367]], [[386, 367]], [[386, 239]]])]

Comment: So you have a list, which contains a numpy array, which contains a list of lists of lists... are all these wrappers really necessary? you should really update your question with that info..

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but
you could also use one of numpy's super fast built in functions:
`np.argmax(data, axis=0)`,
this will return the first maximum occurrence in all the columns, see [numpy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html)

Answer (score 0):

I did it myself

But I want to show the possible answer anyway

```py
import imutils
import cv2
import os, os.path


DIR = 'pics/'
numberOfPictures = len([name for name in os.listdir(DIR) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(DIR, name))])

for i in range(0, numberOfPictures):

    image = cv2.imread('pics/' + str(i) + '.png', 0)
    thresh = cv2.threshold(image, 60, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
    
    cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = cnts[0] if imutils.is_cv2() else cnts[1]
    
    j = 1
    
    for c in cnts:
        M = cv2.moments(c)
        
        if M["m00"] != 0:
            cX = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
            cY = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])
            
        else:
            continue

        def get_max_by_col(c, col):
            return max(c, key=lambda x: x[0][col - 1])[0][col - 1]

        print(get_max_by_col(c, 1))
        print(get_max_by_col(c, 2))
        
        j = j + 1
    
        cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
        cv2.circle(image, (cX, cY), 7, (255, 255, 255), -1)
        cv2.putText(image, "center", (cX - 20, cY - 20), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (255, 255, 255), 2)
    
        cv2.imshow("Image", image)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I get 386 and 367 as max values out of

`c = [[[362 239]], [[362 367]], [[386 367]], [[386 239]]]`